# WEBブラウザでの3本以上の音声ハンドリングについて

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome

**【質問概要】**
　chromeなどブラウザで3本以上のマイク音声を取得したいのですが可能でしょうか？

**【環境】**
当方の環境は以下です。
・Windows 10 pro
・Google Chromeのversion：64.0
・PCにオーディオインターフェース(入力が3本以上あるもの)を接続。
　オーディオインターフェースにマイクを複数本接続。

**【質問詳細】**
ブラウザ(Google Chrome)で音声をハンドリングしたく
javascriptで実装しています。
getUserMedia()とAudioContextを用いて2ch分の音声がブラウザに入ってきているのは確認できたのですが
3ch以降がGoogle Chromeに入ってきません。

音声が入ってきているかの確認は
getUserMedia()やAudioContextを用いてブラウザ上に波形表示をさせて
波形が振れるかで確認しました。

どうすれば3ch以上の音声をchromeでハンドリングできるでしょうか？
Windowsのサウンド設定の「録音」タブで入力を見ても
1ch,2chの音声に対してはメーターが振れますが
オーディオインターフェースの3ch以降に繋いだ際には
メーターが振れません。
Windowsのサウンドドライバー周りの制約かなとも思っているのですが
なにかご存知の方がいらっしゃれば教えていただきたく思います。

Answer (score 0):

> Windowsのサウンド設定の「録音」タブで入力を見ても
>   1ch,2chの音声に対してはメーターが振れますが
>   オーディオインターフェースの3ch以降に繋いだ際には
>   メーターが振れません。

デバイスとして音声を認識していないのであれば、Google Chrome等のアプリケーションは無関係です。
ハードウェアの問題であり製造元に問い合わせるべきです。